# Is it possible to run the Elastic net then the stepwise?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, regularization

The elastic net regularization method and the stepwise method are two well-known methods for variable selection. Recently, I saw an example of variable selection, and in this example, we have a high dimension dataset with high collinearity. The person who has played with this dataset, used firstly the elastic net for selecting the important variables(We call the model with selected variables M1). And then next step, he used the stepwise method on this M1.

I'm confused because these two methods are always considered as "one or the other". Is it feasible/reasonable to use them in tandem like this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *possible* to do this, but it can't be a good idea and I don't see a reason to do it. Stepwise has a lot of problems (discussed in numerous threads here and elsewhere). It sounds like they may have thought they had too many variables in the equation after running elastic net and wanted to further shrink the set.  But a better method would be to change the settings on elastic net.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm a new player for the regularization methodes, could you tell me what kind of settings that we can control/change on elastic net? Or maybe do you have any recommand books/sites of this?

Comment: The seminal paper on elastic net is [Zou and Hastie](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf). On p. 303 they show the naive elastic net which includes two parameters ($\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$) which can be set. The exact method will depend on your software.

Comment: Good paper. I just worked with my data (40+ predictors, high collinearity exist) by runing the elastic net with R(glmnet package, alpha=0.5). But, none of the predictors is chosen by the methode except the intercept. Any explaination for this result? Thank you.

Comment: The natural explanation is that the effects weren't large enough, given your sample size.  It could be something else, but that's the usual thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answe! In your comment you said it's possible to do elastic net + stepwise. But when we use elastic net, it gives shrinkage for the coefficient estimate to reduce the multicollinearity. And now we take the predictors that elastic net choses, to put them into the lm() function in order to execute the step() function. lm() do not handle the multicollinearity, so is it already violate the hypothsis here??

Comment: There might not be multicollinearity, or it might be only in variables that aren't included in variables elastic net chooses.